# Using ERP Movement type data, how to check if a certain sequence of cells is in correct order?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sap-erp

I am very much hoping that someone can help me in finding out a solution to catch errors made by users using SAP.

Here is some context: Before the appropriate validations were put into place, SAP allowed users to post some movement types of ERP without looking first if an actual warehouse had an item before it issues it out to some other warehouse. Numerous errors caused discrepancies between system inventory quantity versus serial number count. Currently, I am looking for the serial numbers that caused these discrepancies.

Just linking this here but you do not really need to read this.
[MOVEMENT TYPES IN ERP](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ERPLO/Movement+types)

Previously, I implemented a way to catch serial numbers that caused discrepancies by using vlookup and pivot tables to see which serial numbers produced a net Goods Receipt-Goods Issuance of negative values; this means that the serial number was issued more times than it was received in stores which is an instant flag for discrepancy. Lately, however, I discovered this method could not catch all errors in serial number postings because a net of 0 could still mean a specific serial number was issued right away (as its first transaction) before it was even received in an issuing warehouse.

Before I implement a pivot table which has been found to be insufficient in finding all faulty serial numbers, I have an extract from ERP that contains all the **movement types of a serial number and the date it was posted**. These are contained in a spreadsheet. Is there a way in Excel to check whether a certain sequence is wrong and should alert me if the serial number should be looked into?

Here is an example:

> Serial number CAE342991's transaction history (in iq03 if anyone wants to know)
>
> 1st transaction: 261
>
> 2nd transaction: 262

Because the first transaction was a 261 issuance, a warehouse deducted quantity from its inventory without even having the serial number. This leads to a discrepancy between system inventory quantity and serial number count because serial numbers are now more than system inventory when they should be equal.

In Excel, is there a method or formula to check if a serial number follows the correct sequence (which I have to set) without having to use Macros?

Excerpt of Excel file I am working on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r56y52ode55zpo8/SAP%20OBJK-SER03%20Extract.xlsx?dl=0

Thank you very much guys

Comment: Instead of testing sum for negative values, you probably should test for negative values running total of moves for each serial ordered chronologically.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not quite understand. Can you kindly elaborate on the negative values running total of moves? In addition, there is no chronological fixed order as the transaction histories of serial numbers mirror what users posted in real life. Do you know of a way to order them chronologically?

Comment: It would be much easier if you could upload some sample data (preferably with your current solution implemented).

Comment: I shall upload a sample Excel file. I will also explain what my desired outcome with the data is.

Comment: @user3964075 Here it is - https://www.dropbox.com/s/r56y52ode55zpo8/SAP%20OBJK-SER03%20Extract.xlsx?dl=0

The important fields are serial number, date and movement type. In our case, if the first transaction of specific serial number is an issuance like a 261, 641 or transfer postings, should be able to catch it. Filtering a single serial number will show you its history. Please tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32206888/edit) the question and include the link there. All important information should be included in question, not comments.

Comment: And you mentioned in your post that you already have some kind of summary with pivot table and vlookup. No one will read the entire ERP movent type manual you included. Please include a file with your current calculations. In your file rows `4:9` have the same date and serial number. Does it mean that the move from row 4 was first, 5 - 2nd and so on? If not - can you generate same file with date and time?

Comment: @user3964075 Thank you for your guidance to make this thread clearer. I have put the link in the question.

Comment: @user3964075 

I apologize for the confusion. The pivot table and vlookup were used to reach the current file I have linked. Another pivot method was used to see the net of issuances vs GRs. It does not catch all the errors.

Please clarify what you mean by calculations?

Regarding rows 4:9, yes, the move row 4 was first, 5 was the second

Comment: You said you already have pivot table to catch negative totals. Looking at the raw data it is not clear if the move should be counted as `+1` or `-1` (issue/receive), so I thought you have a version with a lookup to solve this problem.

Comment: @user3964075 H stands for an issuance while S denotes a receipt. I can show you the pivot table to catch negative totals but I do not think it will help to find serial numbers that have a net of 0 but have an erroneous transaction somewhere in its records.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of moves in sample file is chronological, and `S` stands for `+1` move and `H` for `-1` move, then you can use following formula to calculate running total of moves (enter in `H2` and fill down):

```
=IF(A2=A1,H1,0)+IF(LEFT(E2,1)="S",1,-1)
```

Whenever the running total is negative, it means more items were issued than received. To catch it you can use autofilter, or conditional formatting. To apply conditional formatting to full rows, select whole table and use following formula:

```
=$H1<0
```

I'm not sure if you described all the requirements, because in the sample file over 2000 rows have negative running total.

Image from sample file:

[image]

Comment: Hello @user3964075 thank you for providing this however, I have already implemented a method to catch the running totals of all serial numbers by using a pivot table to tally the net total of H (issuances) and S (receipts)

I could upload it for you if you want to see it. My requirement is that I get to catch serial numbers that had a double consecutive issuance or receipt. That would mean two consecutive H or S. 344 and 343 are just two instances of a movement type that is both an H and S because an item is transferred to another stock type which means it will leave the one it is in now

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution I was looking for and I want to share it for anyone who ever encounters this problem.

To catch serial numbers that have faulty history but have 0 net GR-Issuance difference, here's what I implemented in Excel:

1. Lookup the movement type, plant, storage location, debit/credit, stock type and time fields from SER03
2. Use custom sort with the following levels:
       a. SERIAL NUMBER
       b. DATE 
       c. TIME
       d. DEBIT/CREDIT
   ***this will ensure that the Excel extract reflects the history of each serial number to the letter
3. Concatenate serial number-plant-sloc-stock type-d/c
4. In the next column, use a simple formula to check whether the concatenation of #3 is equal to the cell right below it (e.g. =A1=A2). If the value returned is TRUE, it means that there has been a double issuance or a double goods receipt